# ObtainAuthToken fails with 404 when using local network IP

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to connect an Android device to my `ObtainAuthToken` endpoint from the `django-rest-framework`.

If I just call it with `http://localhost/api-token-auth` it works fine:

```
[21/Dec/2017 16:04:34] "POST /api-token-auth HTTP/1.1" 400 68
```

But if I change that to `http://192.168.1.4/api-token-auth` my dev server throws me a 404, like so:

```
[21/Dec/2017 16:05:00] "POST /api-token-auth HTTP/1.1" 404 0
```

I've tried adding my IP number `192.168.1.4` to `ALLOWED_HOSTS` but no dice. Trying to Google this issue just brings up a bunch of unrelated stuff.

Anyone knows what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue which I resolved by running the Django project on ***0.0.0.0*** rather than ***localhost***.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that I've tried this. Without running the server like this, my development server would not even get the request.